# asp.net - Global.asax not firing on IIS 8.5 with .Net Framework 4.6.2

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-8, global-asax, .net-4.6.2

I have an asp.net webforms with .Net Framework 4.6.2 running in a IIS 8.5 that is not firing the Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute event on Global.asax:

Global.asax.vb

```
Sub Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim Hello = True 'Not firing here!!
End Sub
```

With IIS Express works fine...

Comment: Are you trying to set a break point on the line to see if it works? If so, that line will never work the way you want. The optimizer ends up removing that line because it's not used. Try writing to the debug window.

Comment: How do you know it's not firing that event?

Comment: This "Dim Hello = True" is only for example, the real code is logging the requested page. I know it is working because I debugged and I saw the log on the database, running on a IIS Express. The problem is when I publish this code to IIS 8.5 in QA or Production environment.

Comment: I tried also on "Application_AcquireRequestState" event on Global.asax, but with no success.

Comment: I tried also on web.config "<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />", with no success...

Comment: @Fernando did you ever find the underlying issue here?